# Tap event not detected in Swift Messagekit app?

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I have an app using the standard implementation of `Messagekit` but the `didTapMessage` event isn't firing when I tap the message text (the `didTapAvatar` function isn't run at all either). I'm not using a custom cell so I don't think I need to use a custom gesture recognizer.

Here's the relevant code as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import MessageKit
import MessageInputBar

class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController {

    // MARK: Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        messageInputBar.delegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self

        .....

        }

    // MARK: Properties

    ...
}

extension ChatViewController: MessagesDataSource {

    func currentSender() -> Sender {
        //guard let currentUserID = User.current?.key else {return nil}
        let newSender = Sender(id: (User.current?.key)!, displayName: (User.current?.username)!)
        return newSender
    }

    func numberOfSections(in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> Int {
        //return 1
        return messages.count
    }

    func messageForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageType {
        return messages[indexPath.section]

        func cellTopLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {

            return NSAttributedString(string: MessageKitDateFormatter.shared.string(from: message.sentDate), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray])
        }

        func messageTopLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {
            let name = message.sender.displayName
            return NSAttributedString(string: name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)])
        }

        func messageBottomLabelAttributedText(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {

            let dateString = formatter.string(from: message.sentDate)
            return NSAttributedString(string: dateString, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2)])
        }
    }
}

extension ChatViewController: MessagesDisplayDelegate, MessagesLayoutDelegate {}

extension ChatViewController: MessageCellDelegate {

    func didTapAvatar(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("Avatar tapped")
    }

    func didTapMessage(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("Message tapped")

    }

    func didTapCellTopLabel(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("Top cell label tapped")
    }

    func didTapMessageTopLabel(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("Top message label tapped")
    }

    func didTapMessageBottomLabel(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("Bottom label tapped")
    }

    func didTapAccessoryView(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("Accessory view tapped")
    }
}

extension ChatViewController: MessageInputBarDelegate {
    func messageInputBar(
        _ inputBar: MessageInputBar,
        didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you lost this:

`messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self`

The full implementation reference (from 
 https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit):

```
func configureMessageCollectionView() {

    messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
    messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self

    scrollsToBottomOnKeyboardBeginsEditing = true // default false
    maintainPositionOnKeyboardFrameChanged = true // default false

    messagesCollectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadMoreMessages), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much for this. I can't believe it was that simple. I spent way too much time staring at the code

Comment: do not link a  product home page (the OP is clearly using) and think that that constitutes "advice" you need to cite the actual location